# How to prevent native Keyboard in PhoneGap build (on Android) from closing by itself?

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I have a chat with the following html for input text

Type message...

On Android (haven't tried IOS), when the user clicks the send button, the keyboard closes by itself. I would like to prevent this behaviour. How would I got about it?

I tried to turn off the blur event, but it didn't help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can make a keyboard always visible for an activity by adding the following in the manifest under the activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

So your manifest file should contain something like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

More Information can be found here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried reading up on in, but I'm still not sure what activity  (in the context of Android development), and how it translates to a phonegap project. Will my keyboard always be visible? I don't want that, I want it to be visible only for one page..

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using setOnEditorActionListener or setOnKeyListener ? on both case try your return statement with true.........